# Is plant classes or any crop is present in Imagenet datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working on a project, which is based on plants. I only want to know that whether Imagenet datasets include tree, crop classes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many kinds of plants in Imagenet. [image-net.org](http://image-net.org) has a search feature. For example, http://image-net.org/search?q=tree

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does include some: see [here](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a) for Imagenet 1000, e.g.

- 985: 'daisy'
- 987: 'corn'
- 988: 'acorn',