# How to extract plant images from imagenet

Tags: image

Imagenet, including the mini datasets you can find on Kaggle have many plant images but their annotations do not make it apparent that they are plants (at least, to a computer). Does anyone know of a relatively painless way to extract plant images from imagenet?

Note: I have seen this response ([Is plant classes or any crop is present in Imagenet datasets?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68252/is-plant-classes-or-any-crop-is-present-in-imagenet-datasets)) and it is outdated, so please don't suggest it.